# How to use request module in node.js lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the request module in AWS Lambda for Node.js, but I am not having good results.

This is the function I have so far:

```
const request = require('request');
url = 'https://www.google.com'

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    request(url, (error,res,body) => {
        console.log(error);    //this is not printing
        console.log(res);      //this is not printing
        console.log(body);     //this is not printing
        console.log('Come on!!'); //this is not printing
    });

    console.log(url); //This is the only thing printing, you can see in the Function Logs below, second line.

};
```

and this is the response I am getting:

```
Response:
null

Request ID:
"3e46f401-f26d-435d-90be-ac848c6c3a39"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 3e46f401-f26d-435d-90be-ac848c6c3a39 Version: $LATEST
2019-10-14T08:06:23.755Z    3e46f401-f26d-435d-90be-ac848c6c3a39    INFO    https://www.google.com
END RequestId: 3e46f401-f26d-435d-90be-ac848c6c3a39
REPORT RequestId: 3e46f401-f26d-435d-90be-ac848c6c3a39  Duration: 368.93 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 92 MB  Init Duration: 461.54 ms
```

I am wondering why I am not getting any response from inside the requests method. I tried on my laptop and the part of the code outside the handler works just fine.

I uploaded the project as a zip file, so the node_modules folder with the request module is indeed there.
I noted a couple of solutions using the http module instead of request, but I would like to understand first why this is not working, before moving to a different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is marked as `async`, yet you are using a callback to handle the response. So nothing is being `awaited` on.

This means that your function returns an implicit promise that is already fulfilled. This makes the lambda stop. So, either:

A) Write your code using async/await, which probably requires `request-promise` or similar:

```
exports.handler = async event => {
    const res = await promisifiedRequest(url);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(url);
};
```

or

B) Convert the function from `async/await` to use callbacks, like so:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const res = request(url, (error, res, body) => {
        console.log('Come on!!');
        callback(null, res.statusCode);
    });
    console.log(url);
};
```